# adding 2 documents to firestore one is using a reference from the other?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to created 2 docs at ones what first docs id is used in the second. One problems is my code look wired, especially the chaining. I am afraid even if it works that it might be wrong.

Any idea for a more clear refactor? The flow is the following:

1. signup a user
2. get his created id created a new collection
3. get the new collection id then
4. create the final doc with the user id and with id of the previously created collection as a reference in the last doc.

```js
const Signup = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        const user = userCredential.user;
        const colRef = collection(db, 'Shared');
        addDoc(colRef, {
          sharedValue: '',
        }).then((res) =>
          setDoc(doc(db, 'Data', user.uid), {
            sharedId: res.id,
          })
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the documentation on [adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document):

> In some cases, it can be useful to create a document reference with an auto-generated ID, then use the reference later. For this use case, you can call `doc()`.
>
> ```
> import { collection, doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 
>
> // Add a new document with a generated id
> const newCityRef = doc(collection(db, "cities"));
>
> // later...
> await setDoc(newCityRef, data);
> ```

So:

```
await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    const user = userCredential.user;
    const colRef = collection(db, 'Shared');
    const docRef = doc(db, 'Shared');
    setDoc(docRef, {
      sharedValue: '',
    }).then((res) =>
      setDoc(doc(db, 'Data', user.uid), {
        sharedId: docRef.id,
      })
    );
  })
  .catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
  });
};
```